# Programmatically select item from list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list with NavigationLinks in it. I wish to programmatically select/tap an item from the list. I tried using NavigationLink(tag..., selection...) API, but looks like it's deprecated from iOS 16.

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct BookItem {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let bookList: [BookItem] = [BookItem.init(id: 0, name: "History"), BookItem.init(id: 1, name: "Math"), BookItem.init(id: 2, name: "Science")]

    let selectBookItemId: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List(bookList, id: \.name) { bookItem in
                    NavigationLink(destination: { DetailsView(bookItem: bookItem) },
                    label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(bookItem.name)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    })
     
                    // NOTE: Was going to use this, but it is deprecated
//                    NavigationLink(
//                        destination: ,
//                        tag:,
//                        selection:,
//                        label: {})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    var bookItem: BookItem

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(bookItem.name).font(.body.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

In my sample code above, let's say I wish to programmatically select 2nd item from the list i.e. when I execute the code, it should show me DetailsView with "Math" written on it.

How can it be achieved now since NavigationLink API is deprecated?

Thanks!

Edit: With @son's answer, I was able to solve my original question. I thought it will work with my actual app data, but my data is more complex. I need to pass an array objects to destination view and when I try to do that I am getting an error.

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct BookItem: Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let listing: [String]
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, listing: [String]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.listing = listing
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let bookList: [BookItem] = [BookItem.init(id: 0, name: "History", listing: ["1", "2"]),
                                BookItem.init(id: 1, name: "Math", listing: ["1", "2"]),
                                BookItem.init(id: 2, name: "Science", listing: ["1", "2"])]

    let selectBookItemId: Int
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                List(bookList, id: \.name) { bookItem in
                    Button {
                        path.append(bookItem.listing)
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(bookItem.name)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self, destination: { listing in
                DetailsView(bookItem: listing)
            })
            .onAppear { //<- append book at index here
                if let book = bookList.first(where: {$0.id == selectBookItemId}) {
                    path.append(book.listing)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    var bookItem: [String]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           // Text(bookItem.name).font(.body.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}

Error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[String]'
```

Comment: It still works, what do you expect? Not all of NavigationLink is deprecated, you can use it inside a NavigationStack.

Comment: It works for now for iOS 16, may not soon work with future iOS versions. So was looking for alternate ways.

Comment: There are several existing questions and answers on this. Please see the following [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NavigationLink+deprecated). The documentation for the deprecated link also offers suggestions and a link to [Migrating to new navigation types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types).

Comment: I did search through SO and most of the answers are old which doesn't help anymore. Also suggestions I see in Xcode is to use navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:) or NavigationLink(value:label:) which doesn't do anything with selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way is to use `NavigationPath`. You could try this:

```swift
@State private var path = NavigationPath()

let selectBookItemId: Int

NavigationStack(path: $path) {
    VStack { 
        List(bookList, id: \.name) { bookItem in
            Button {
                path.append(bookItem)
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text(bookItem.name)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: BookItem.self, destination: { book in
        DetailsView(bookItem: book)
    })
    .onAppear { //<- here
        if let book = bookList.first(where: {$0.id == selectBookItemId}) {
            path.append(book)
        }
    }
}
```

And the `BookItem` must conform `Hashable`

```swift
struct BookItem: Hashable {
    ...
}
```

And passing id in such as:

```
ContentView(selectBookItemId: 1)
```

Comment: This does not programmatically select the item. It does navigate to DetailsView but only when I tap on an item. I want the app/program to tap on an item automatically when view is launched.

Comment: Ok, I got your idea and updated the answer.

Comment: Would you know if it's possible to pass an array of objects using NavigationDestination(for...) api? Just to keep the post simple, I had created a simple data, but in my app, I am actually passing an array of objects to the destination view. I have only used NavigationDestination(isPreseneted..) before. When I try to pass an array, I am getting an error. I will edit my question and add more code to it.

Comment: if you want me to add it as another question than plz let me know. I tried NavigationDestination(for: [String.self]...) but that didn't work. And I didn't find examples where people are sending an array to the destination.

Comment: Ignore my question. I figured out how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't check the notification. Take your time.